# Eclipse Plugin Development: IMarker no text highlight

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a probleem with IMarker (or Eclipse annotations) in my developed Eclipse editor. I get annotation to ruler and I get annotation in markers tab. But no text highlighted.
I tried IMarker.PROBLEM and also made my own marker type but no help.

Example with bookmarks annotation. In preferences made some changes but still, annotation on ruler but not text highlight.

[image: Picture from preferences]
[image: And my editor, with no lighlight]

Comment: Annotation preference changes usually require an editor restart. Which editor is this?

Comment: This is my own developed editor. Problem already solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had overridden method initializeEditor in my editor class(class that extends TextEdtor). No annotation prefrences info where got.

What a mistake...